# how to property delete PersistentVolume in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using this command to delete PersistentVolume:

```
  ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Document/source/config/k8s/redis ⌚ 12:23:38
$ kubectl delete -f pv.yaml
persistentvolume "nfs-pv1" deleted
persistentvolume "nfs-vp2" deleted
persistentvolume "nfs-pv3" deleted
persistentvolume "nfs-pv4" deleted
persistentvolume "nfs-pv5" deleted
persistentvolume "nfs-pv6" deleted
```

but the progress is stuck.How to smoothly remove the persistentvolume?I check the kubernetes dashboard(kubernetes version v1.15.2) and found `nfs-pv5` volume still remain.I have tried to tweak the service using persistentvolume scale 0(stopping all pods using persistentvolume) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user deletes a PVC in active use by a Pod, the PVC is not removed immediately. PVC removal is postponed until the PVC is no longer actively used by any Pods. Also, if an admin deletes a PV that is bound to a PVC, the PV is not removed immediately. PV removal is postponed until the PV is no longer bound to a PVC.

You can see that a PVC is protected when the PVC’s status is Terminating and the Finalizers list includes kubernetes.io/pvc-protection.

So you need to delete the pod first and then delete the PVC and then delete PV or you can edit the pv and pvc to remove the finalizer.

```
kubectl patch pvc PVC_NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
kubectl patch pvc PV_NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
```